# Static linking libcurl using c

Tags: c, curl, gnu, static-linking

I am using Libcurl in my application with C and GNU compiler on a linux machine.
Application also uses OpenSSL libraries and some other libraries. I am trying to statically link the libraries, except for `lcurl` linking with other libraries works fine.

I am trying to compile as below.

```
gcc -static -I. -o test test.c -lz -lssl -lcrypto -lcurl
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
Is there a way to force static linking of some librairies (libc for exemple) ?

Comment: What is the actual problem you encounter? I would guess curl sits in another directory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libcurl is itself linked against a *ton* of other libraries, most of which aren't included in your compile command line. For instance, mine (on Debian Squeeze) links against:

- libc
- libcom_err
- libcrypto
- libdl
- libgcrypt
- libgnutls
- libgpg-error
- libgssapi_krb5
- libidn
- libk5crypto
- libkeyutils
- libkrb5
- libkrb5support
- liblber-2.4
- libldap_r-2.4
- libpthread
- libresolv
- librt
- libsasl2
- libssh2
- libssl
- libtasn1
- libz

(You can get a similar list for yourself by running `ldd` on the library on Linux, or `otool -L` on Darwin.)